# Changing cells in range according to data in another range

Tags: excel, vba

How do I change cell data in a range according to data filter in another range?

I want to first identify if values from E11 to G13 are 0.
If 0, change the corresponding cells in Range O9 to Q11 to 0.
If not 0, keep the original values in Range O9 to Q11.

```vb
Sub If_loop2()
    For Each Cell In Range("O9:Q11")
        If Range("E11:G13").Value = 0 Then
            Cell.Value = 0
        Else
            Cell.Value = Cell.Value
        End If
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there are many ways to solve this, but since each cell is referenced another cell at a specific offset from it (2 rows up and 10 rows to the left), we can use Offset to check the relevant cell and do the needful:

```
Sub If_loop2()
    For Each c In Range("O9:Q11")
        If c.Offset(2, -10) = 0 Then
            c.Value = 0
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Without using Offset, we can loop over one of the ranges in order using a cells property of the range (it will loop from left to right, like reading a book). Then compare to the cell in the other range, with the same index:

```
Sub If_loop3()

Dim r1 As Range
Dim r2 As Range
    
    Set r1 = Range("O9:Q11")
    Set r2 = Range("E11:G13")
    
    For i = 1 To r1.Count
        If r2.Cells(i) = 0 Then
            r1.Cells(i) = 0
        End If
    Next i
            
End Sub
```

###### P.S. a non-VBA solution

It can often be preferable to use a non-VBA solution, as non-VBA solutions are easy to understand and maintain. So to that end, simply create a third range with some standard `IF()` formulas.

For example, in cell `O13` use the formula `=IF(E11=0,0,O9)` and copy this formula across two more cells and down two cells. The output will also agree with the desired results (i.e., if `E11` is zero, return 0, otherwise return the value of `O9`). Now you can work in the ranges E11:G13 and O9:Q11 as much as you want, and the "output" range in O13:Q15 will keep track of these comparisons.

Comment: Thanks this helps a lot! Is there any other ways to solve this? If you don't want to count the specific offset of another reference cell. how would you solve this? Really appreciate it

Comment: I've added an answer without Offset

Comment: Thanks so much, really appreciate your answer, that is exactly what I need